# Query list of entities with embedded entity using objectify

Tags: android, google-app-engine, objectify

I have a simple @Entity class with the standard @Id Long id and several fields. One of those fields is a Map.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{

@Id Long id;

@Index String fieldOne;  
@Unindex int fieldTwo;  
@Unindex int fieldThree; 
@Unindex Map<String, MyPojo> map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

From what I have gathered, Objectify treats this map as if it were an embedded entity. 
When I query for a list using:

```
List<MyEntity> list = ofy().load().type(MyEntity.class).filter("fieldOne =", fieldList).list();
```

The query executes fine but when I try to do anything with the list I get this exception

> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EmbeddedEntity

This exception is also thrown when I touch the query after using these methods as well:

```
  Map<Long, MyEntity> query = ofy().load().type(MyEntity.class).ids(idsList);
```

or

```
   Map<Key<MyEntity>, MyEntity> query= ofy().load().keys(iterableOfKeys);
```

Now in some testing I found that if I change my map to

```
   @Unindex Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

everything works great. All the above queries work and I can iterate on them and so on and so forth. So my question is what am I missing? Am I attempting this all wrong or is there a better way of going about this?

I am using the latest version Objectify 5.1.12.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace and the definition of MyPojo?

Comment: After not solving it I built a work around to move on. After seeing your comment, I went back and reverted that field to use the Map<String, MyPojo> to make it fail again to gather a stacktrace and it didn't. Everything works now. I'm very confused. Before this came about I had the map field as an Index List and the problems arose when I changed it to Unindex Map. Perhaps the Indexing caused the problem and it took several hours for the Index change to take place. Now that the map works, I am unable to get MyPojo from the JsonMap returned on the client side. Casting does not work. Any Thoughts

Comment: I genuinely don't understand what you are asking. When asking questions, describe the steps you took leading up to the issue and post full stacktraces. If you have stored data in your database that is not in the "shape" of your java classes, you can have all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting the class definition of `MyPojo` I assume it is not define as `@Entity` From the Objectify documentation:

> The value can be any type that can be persisted as a field, including basic types, ***embedded objects***, and collections.

Assuming this is your `MyPojo` it should look like this:

```
  @Entity
  class MyPojo {
      String firstName;
      String lastName;
      Integer age;
  }
```

The reason it worked with your change is because you had used a basic type for the value of the map.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue when I had modified the structure of an existing entity and queried it after the change.

Comment: How is this response answering the question?